# Metal raytracing: find all intersections along ray in order from nearest to farthest

Tags: ios, metal

I am using the Metal raytracing apis to intersect an acceleration structure of axis aligned bounding boxes. For my use, I need to find all intersections along a ray in a predictable order (ideally nearest to farthest)

I'm currently using `intersection_query` to find the intersections. However the order in which intersections are returned does appear to be dependable

Is there some to get distance-ordered results from an `intersection_query`? If not, is there another way to get ordered intersections with the Metal raytracing apis?

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't give you the ability to sort the intersections or get a list of them, you only get one intersection result or committed intersection, but you can probably do something along the following lines.

This is not really API specific. First you find the nearest intersection, then spawning a new ray at that point, until you run out of things to intersect. You would need to configure your query and intersector depending on whether you want backface intersections, but also you need to set `accept_any_intersection` to false.

If you spawn the next ray exactly at the intersection point, there's a chance that it will self-intersect. The obvious way of just increasing `min_distance` on the ray is not really correct. The easy way is to offset the ray origin along the geometry normal at the point of intersection. But the best way is described in a paper called "[A Fast and Robust Method for Avoiding Self-Intersection by Carsten Wächter and Nikolaus Binder NVIDIA](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4842-4427-2_6.pdf)"